# controller reloads even though reloadOnSearch is set false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, url-routing

i build a webpage where I have several views but only one controller. As the controller should not reload on page switch I changed all the routes to "/main/{{itemNo}}/?routname". However when switching pages the controller is still reloaded (so the language is always switched back to german even though english was selected). Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is some of my code:

This is part of the app.js with the new routes:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/main/1/cart', {
        templateUrl: 'views/cart.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main',
        reloadOnSearch: false
      })
      .when('/main/2/personaldata', {
        templateUrl: 'views/personalData.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main',
        reloadOnSearch: false
      })
```

This is my controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    // console.log('init');




    $('#german').click(function () {
      changeValue('german');
    });

    $('#english').click(function () {
      changeValue('english');
    });

    $('#toshoppingcart').click(function () {
      setTimeout(function() {
        changeValue(selectedLang);
      }, 10);
    });

    $('#tocheckout').click(function () {
      setTimeout(function() {
        changeValue(selectedLang);
      }, 10);
    });



    var loadScript = function (src, callbackfn) {
      var newScript = document.createElement("script");
      newScript.type = "text/javascript";
      newScript.setAttribute("async", "true");
      newScript.setAttribute("src", src);

      if (newScript.readyState) {
        newScript.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (/loaded|complete/.test(newScript.readyState)) callbackfn();
        }
      } else {
        newScript.addEventListener("load", callbackfn, false);
      }

      document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(newScript);
    };


    function changeValue(language) {
      console.log('change', language)
      selectedLang = language;
      if (language == 'english') {
        loadScript("scripts/languages/english.js", function () {
          updateValues()
        });
      } else {
        loadScript("scripts/languages/german.js", function () {
          updateValues()
        });
      }
    }

    var selectedLang = 'german';
    changeValue(selectedLang);
```

Comment: Side note, any reason you're using jQuery ID selectors instead of `ng-click` ?

Comment: it was a normal js project before without any fw, right now i changed it to angular as I also had the reload problem

Comment: You may need to store `selectedLang` in a different location rather than the controller constructor scope, perhaps on `$rootScope`, because every time the controller gets called (every route that you use it) your `selectedLang` variable is defined as `german` instead of the previously deffined value. Am I right?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro yes thats the problem, but i thought if i add the reloadOnSearch = false, the controller is not reloaded and the value is not set back to german? Or is this wrong? but you mean, if i store it as a rootscope variable i will not be overwritten?

Comment: `reloadOnSearch = false` will prevent your route to reload when you change parameters (aka, search) or hash like `?q=blablabal` and `#/my-route#myHash`. Instead of realoding it will trigger `$routeUpdate` on `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `reloadOnSearch = false` will prevent your route to reload when you change parameters (aka, search) or hash like `?q=blablabal` and `#/my-route#myHash`. Instead of realoding it will trigger `$routeUpdate` on `$rootScope`. In your case, you aren't using either of them, you are changing the entire route, therefore it will reload the route.

According to the docs for [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider):

> `[reloadOnSearch=true]` - `{boolean=}` - reload route when only `$location.search()` or  `$location.hash()` changes.
>
> If the option is set to `false` and url in the browser changes, then `$routeUpdate` event is broadcasted on the root scope.

Also, you have to store `selectedLang` in a different location rather than the controller constructor scope, perhaps on `$rootScope` or `localstorage`, because every time the controller gets called (every route that you use it) your `selectedLang` variable is defined as `'german'` instead of the previously deffined value.

Try something like this (of course, consider using the angular way of doing this, this is just an example):

```
function changeValue(language) {
  console.log('change', language)
  selectedLang = window.localStorage['language'] = language;
  if (language == 'english') {
    loadScript("scripts/languages/english.js", function () {
      updateValues()
    });
  } else {
    loadScript("scripts/languages/german.js", function () {
      updateValues()
    });
  }
}

var selectedLang = window.localStorage['language'] || 'german';
changeValue(selectedLang);
```